# Create Task Pane Office Add-In for Outlook 2016

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook, office-addins, office-2016

I am trying to create an add-in for Outlook 2016. In previous versions of Office, this was done using a WinForms UserControl and was fairly simple. However, there are now universal templates in Visual Studio 2015 for an *Office Add In*, which I would like to use, rather than the Outlook VSTO Add In (both shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knEe6.png)).

My issue is that when selecting the new *Office Add In* template, Visual Studio then asks what application(s) this plug in is for, and as shown, there is not an [option for Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c52YD.png).

So, I would like to know how I can create a custom Task Pane for Outlook 2016 using the new Office Templates?

Apologies for the links to images, I don't yet have enough rep to directly add them to questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo). In this example, JavaScript and HTML are used. Here is an example of the JavaScript that pulls data from the selected email:

```
  Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();

        loadProps();
    });
};

   function loadProps() {
  var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

  $('#dateTimeCreated').text(item.dateTimeCreated.toLocaleString());
  $('#dateTimeModified').text(item.dateTimeModified.toLocaleString());
  $('#itemClass').text(item.itemClass);
  $('#itemId').text(item.itemId);
  $('#itemType').text(item.itemType);

  if (item.itemType == Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Message){
    loadMessageProps(item);
  }
  else {
    loadAppointmentProps(item);
  }
}
```

This is then linked to a HTML page to display the data. In order to add this to Outlook, there is also an XML manifest file. This tells outlook where to find the pages, here is a snippet of the file:

```
<Requirements>
  <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
  </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
<Hosts>
  <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
    <DesktopFormFactor>
      <!-- Message read form -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
          <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
            <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip" />
            <!-- Task pane button -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
              <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
              <Tooltip resid="paneReadButtonTooltip" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
              </Icon>
              <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
              </Action>
            </Control>
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>
```

Hope this helps others as it helped me.